# remove a value from firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm trying to delete a node from Firebase database but nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(keyPath);

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
    .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name").removeValue()
```

This is the output:

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>   SLF4J:See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details.
>
> 09-02-2018 05:43:53 PM - [START]  - Start action : Statement -
>   serviceAccount = new java.io.FileInputStream(keyPath) 09-02-2018
>   05:43:53 PM - [END]    - End action : Statement - serviceAccount = new
>   java.io.FileInputStream(keyPath) 09-02-2018 05:43:53 PM - [START]  -
>   Start action : Statement - options = new
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder().setCredentials(com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)).setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl).build()
>   09-02-2018 05:43:53 PM - [END]    - End action : Statement - options =
>   new
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder().setCredentials(com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)).setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl).build()
>   09-02-2018 05:43:53 PM - [START]  - Start action : Statement -
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options) 09-02-2018
>   05:43:53 PM - [END]    - End action : Statement -
>   com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options) 09-02-2018
>   05:43:53 PM - [START]  - Start action : Statement - ref =
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
>   09-02-2018 05:43:53 PM - [END]    - End action : Statement - ref =
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
>   09-02-2018 05:43:53 PM - [START]  - Start action : Statement
>   ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name").removeValue() 09-02-2018
>   05:43:53 PM - [END]    - End action : Statement -
>   ref.child("Users").child(uid).child("name").removeValue() 09-02-2018
>   05:43:53 PM - [PASSED] - Test Cases/V2/General/Draft 09-02-2018
>   05:43:53 PM - [END]    - End Test Case : Test Cases/V2/General/Draft

As I said, nothing changes on the database.
Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your database structure? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found this repository on github:  https://github.com/bane73/firebase4j
In the readme file, there is a simple example of writing a value to firebase database by providing only the database url and the data you want to write.
In order to delete a value, just set the value to null:

```
String url = 'https://project-name.firebaseio.com/users/user1/email'

//Initialize database
Firebase firebase = new Firebase(baseUrl);

//remove email of user1
Map<String, Object> dataMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
dataMap.put("some str", null);
firebase.put(dataMap)
```